# continuous variable $X$ such that $\Pr(X=x) \neq 0$, for some value $x$.

Tags: probability-distributions

I'm interested in cases where you have a probability function $\Pr$ defined over the values of the continuous real valued variable $X$, where some particular value or values have non-zero, non-unitary probability, and the remaining probability is distributed over intervals.

I'm inclined to deal with such cases by combining a density function $f$, defined over all values of $X$ and a mass function $m$ defined over some countable subset of values of $X$, $\mathbf{x} = \{ x_1, x_2, \dots \}$, such that
$$
\int_{X} f(x)\hspace{4pt} dx \quad +\quad \sum_{x_i \in \mathbf{x}} m(x_i) = 1
$$
and then defining
$$
\Pr(X \in [a, b]) = \int_a^b f(x) \hspace{4pt}dx \quad + \quad \sum_{\substack{ x_i \in \mathbf{x}: \\ x_i \in [a, b]}} m(x_i)
$$

However, I don't see such mixed density/mass distributions discussed in any of the texts I usually consult on probability theory.  Is there a standard way of dealing with such problems other than this?  Or are there issues for this way of proceeding?  Any guidance would be much appreciated.

Comment: I see it as a sum of two random variables one of which is discrete and the other is continuous and each has his own way of calculations.

Comment: Check out the [Tweedie distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tweedie_distribution)